# Make a link non-secure

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, hyperlink, anchor

I have a JavaScript link that is as follows:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('TrackPackage.asp?track=235&ship=OTHER&ShippingMethod=1', '', 'location=1,menubar=1,scrollbars=1,status=1,resizable=1,width=635,height=460'); return false;">
<span class="PageText_L288n">TRACK YOUR PACKAGE</span>
</a>
```

However, it is being linked from a secure page, so it becomes a secure page. Unfortunately this creates a problem for me since a unsecured form is automatically submitted when they arrive at the page. They get prompted: this form is being submitted insecurely. There isn't any sensitive data on those pages so I really don't need the page to be secured in the first place. Is there an attribute, either in HTML or JavaScript that could make a link not secure. I cannot really modify the link itself because it's a dynamic link.

However, I do believe some jQuery can add `http://www.example.com/` before the `TrackPackage.asp`. I guess that would be acceptable, but I'd prefer some kind of attribute that will just make the link non secure. Thanks

Comment: You confused me about which page is at HTTPS and which isn't. Generally, you can avoid security warnings by always linking to HTTPS-urls (but, obviously, you'd have to specify the full URL to that TrackPackage.asp). Alternatively, use protocol-less URLs (e.g. "//google.com"), as that should open the referenced URL over the protocol that is the same as the calling page. Unrelated, it'd be friendlier if you used `<a href="TrackPackage.asp" target="_blank">click me</a>`, as that would open new window/tab w/o the risk of being blocked by popup blockers (just a thought; I hate popups).

Comment: @Hari The calling page is HTTPS, I'm trying to get the TrackPackage.asp page to be HTTP. I can't modify the link so I'd have to use JavaScript or jQuery

Comment: The protocol is specified in the URL, so adding http://domain to the start of the URL is the best way to solve this issue. There is no attribute to change protocol.

Comment: Of course you can modify the link - immediately after you receive that HTML from the 3rd party, you'll have at least one opportunity to do that - e.g. use js+jquery to change link's attributes and all you want. I've never seen the browser warning about HTTPS-to-HTTP; I saw the opposite. But, anyways, you can change the URL (and with it, the protocol), even if it's conditional (http or https depending on something).

Comment: @Hari Okay, so my knowledge of jQuery is very limited. How would I be able to add the `http://www.example.com` to the start of the URL?

Comment: I added a sample of what you could be looking for as an answer below,

Comment: What Cheery typed below should also work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try to override native function. But in some browsers that may not work (did not find such browser, so assume that it works in all, at least major, browsers :) ):

```
var windowOpen = window.open;
window.open = function(url, name, settings) {
    var url = 'http://www.example.com/' + url;
    alert("New url = " + url);
    windowOpen(url, name, settings);  
}
```

If you want to do it for a selected class of the links then you can do it like this (the idea of the onclick attribute modification as a text string is not the best one)

```
<script>
var windowOpen = window.open, clicked = false;
window.open = function(url, name, settings) {
    if (clicked) var url = 'http://www.example.com/' + url;
    alert("New url = " + url);
    windowOpen(url, name, settings);  
}
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('span.packagetracklink').click(function(){
        clicked = true;
        setTimeout(function(){clicked = false;}, 200);  
   });
});
</script>
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('some_url', '', ''); return false;">
<span class="packagetracklink">TRACK YOUR PACKAGE</span>
</a><br>
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('some_url', '', ''); return false;">
<span class="another_class">TRACK YOUR PACKAGE</span>
</a>
```

Comment: Perfect, how do I call this on specific anchors only?

Comment: Like anchors that are the parent of `span.packagetracklink`

Comment: @user1090389 There is not way to do it. Overridden function does not know from which element it is called. Is there any difference in the URL?

Comment: I'd prefer if this JavaScript is only called on specific links jQuery wouldn't allow me to do so?

Comment: @user1090389   It is possible to do something, to adapt script to your request. Modification of the onclick attribute as a text is not the best way.

Comment: @user1090389    May be you have problem with inclusion of jQuery? Check error console in browser for any messages. It is not supposed to work differently in different modes.

Answer (score 0):

If you receive dynamically the .asp page before using it in the window.open you could just make a String replace to substitute the "https" for an "http" protocol in the URL or in case there's any protocol, add the "http" at the beginning of if.

I haven't tried this since I don't have an https page to play with but I think it can work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to somehow be able to get the instance of that A tag first. It doesn't have an ID or CLASS, so you're on your own there (unless you paste parent element code and siblings code, at least snippets.

```
var link = $("a"); // I don't have enough info to tell you how to precisely get this instance
var originalOnClick = link.attr("onclick");
var part1 = "window.open('"; // this is always the same, right?
var part2 = originalOnClick.substr(part1.length); // the remainder, beginning with TrackPackage.asp
var newOnClick = part1 + "http://www.example.com/" + part2;

link.attr("onclick", newOnClick);
```

There are other ways to inject a string constant into existing string, but this should work - if I understood you well enough.

Comment: I don't know why but this solution did not work... I'd prefer to use your solution since I can select which links to change.

Comment: paste parent element code and siblings code, so that I can see how to select those a-tags. or, if you're receiving that markup as string/text within javascript, then try this - assuming: `var  html = "<a onclick=\"...\"></a>";`, try: `var link = $("a:first", html);`. Then continue from line 2 in above code.

Comment: Hi, I'm having problems with Cheery's code, I was wondering if you're script would be able to work with jQuery 1.4.2 since I know that's the problem...